# How to add Series data in Highcharts from MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, highcharts

Using this JFiddle example of Highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/yxz80f4u/9/

We can see data being input as

```
[Date.UTC(YYYY,MM,DD,HH,MM,SS), Y-data-point]

 data: [
           [Date.UTC(1970, 7, 5,1,1,1), 2.22],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 7, 5,2,2,1), 1.15],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 7, 5,2,30,1), 1.15],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 7, 5,3,50,1), 0],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 7, 5,10,50,1), 2.5],
        ]
```

And it is working perfectly. Now the problem is how can I do the same thing but
 Using arrays of datapoints.

Year_array = ["5/7/1970 1:1:1 AM" , " another year ",  etc....]
Datapoints= [2.22,1.15, etc...]

OR from my controller

```
        graph_points.year.Add("2015, 1, 2, 9, 29, 00");
        graph_points.year.Add("20015, 1, 2, 9, 31, 00");
        graph_points.chlorine.Add(10.1);
        graph_points.chlorine.Add(10.12);
```

So how can I do the same thing when I have two arrays of data points as seen?

UPDATE:

Hi sir, thank you for you suggestion. Do you mean something like this?

```
   for (var i = 0; i < year.length; i++) {
            myseries.push(Date.UTC(year[i]),chlorine[i]);

        }
```

UPDATE: 
Hi Sir, thank you again, one last question ! 
I did what you said

```
            for (var i = 0; i < year.length; i++) {
            var datapoint = [];
            var d = new Date(Date.parse());
            datapoint.push(year[i]);  // Year =2/01/2015 9:45:00 AM (format)

            datapoint.push(chlorine[i]);
            data.push(datapoint);
```

But it returns  00:00:00 on the x-axis for some reason

[image]

Comment: create a new array variable with 2 members, one for date and one for the Datapoints. Then push each array into a new data array, so that you get something like in point 2 [link] http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<line>.data here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

code like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < Year_array.length; i++){
    var dataPoint = [];
    dataPoint.push(Year_array(i); dataPoint.push(Datapoints(i));
    data.push(dataPoint);
    }
```

Comment: What format should Year_array be?  (2/1/2015 1:1:1 AM) ? or

Comment: @JohnLington data in your code would correspond to myseries. But anyway you can totally define an array as var data = []; before your for loop. The year format you've got is fine for Highcharts, funnily enough right at the moment you posted your question I was doing exactly the same thing with a "5/7/1970 1:1:1 AM" kind of format...HighChart treats dates as strings if you don't specify type: datetime ( see [link]http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats )

Comment: thank you so much, one last thing, I'm getting 00:00:00 on my x-axis. Please see update.

Comment: @JohnLington, this is a tricky thing with Highcharts because it ries to automatically size the axis and interval..It seems thought that your data is correct because all your events are happening on the same day a few seconds away from each other..try using pointInterval and pointIntervalUnit (see [link] http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<line>.pointInterval)

Comment: Update - try converting the date time to milliseconds and then passing it to Highcharts, remembering to set the type of the date to 'datetime'..I tried this and Highcharts automatically re-converted the milisecond values back to the correct date

Comment: Oh wow that was amazing. Yeah by changing datetime to milliseconds and using it as (long int) it worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help this was a headache for a long time.